# Flutter - how to make an array of List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

```
class Transactions {
  final String id;

  final double amount;
  final String date;
  

  const Transactions({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.amount,
    @required this.date,
   
  });}
```

I am trying to ad a transaction to the current month . When the user adds a transaction based on the current moth is I would like to add that transaction to the array,e

so I want to make a list of list of `Transactions`

this is what i have tried :

```
  List<List> _userTransactions = [
            List<Transactions> jan= [];
            List<Transactions> feb= [];
            List<Transactions> mar= [];
            List<Transactions> apr= [];
            List<Transactions> may= [];
            .....
            ];
```

it is giving me this error:

[image]

and I am also struggling  trying to add to the list
I am not sure about the logic

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: i have just edited the question

Comment: so you have show us the place of th error — but not th error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my mind, [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Map-class.html) is more convenient choice, because you can set months as keys. It's like an associative array.

```dart
 Map<int, List> _userTransactions = {
   DateTime.january: [],
   DateTime.february: [],
   DateTime.march: [],
   DateTime.april: [],
   DateTime.may: [],
   };
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i know the answer.

You can try it like this:

```
List<List> _userTransactions = [
        <Transactions>[],
        <Transactions>[],
        <Transactions>[],
        <Transactions>[],
        <Transactions>[],
        .....
        ];
```

or if you want to reuse those widgets you can do it like this:

```
List<Transactions> jan= [];
List<Transactions> feb= [];
List<Transactions> mar= [];
List<Transactions> apr= [];
List<Transactions> may= [];

List<List> _userTransactions = [
        jan,
        feb,
        mar,
        apr,
        may,
        .....
        ];
```

Hope i've answered you. Happy coding:)

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
List<List<Transactions>> _userTransactions=[
            List<Transactions> jan= [];
            List<Transactions> feb= [];
            List<Transactions> mar= [];
            List<Transactions> apr= [];
            List<Transactions> may= [];
            .....
            ];
```

That Should Work